# Struct inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

Can a `struct` be inherited in C++?

Answer (score 360):

Yes, `struct` is exactly like `class` except the default accessibility is `public` for `struct` (while it's `private` for `class`).

Comment: This is even the case in C++98, which I was surprised to learn, since all of my C++ textbooks leave out struct inheritance.

Answer (score 158):

Yes. The inheritance is public by default.

Syntax (example):

```
struct A { };
struct B : A { };
struct C : B { };
```

Answer (score 58):

Other than what Alex and Evan have already stated, I would like to add that a C++ struct is not like a C struct.

In C++, a struct can have methods, inheritance, etc. just like a C++ class.

Comment: a C++ struct can be like a C struct. When it is, its called a POD - Plain Old Datatype. It is an important distinction, since for example, only POD structs can be part of unions.

Comment: But PODs can have methods, so are not "like" C structs in the sense which cgorshing is talking about.

Comment: If it's a POD, it doesn't have methods. Otherwise the name is meaningless.

Comment: [With these new rules a lot more types can be PODs now.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189821/10902172) @RL-S

Answer (score 36):

In C++, a structure's inheritance is the same as a class except the following differences:

When deriving a struct from a class/struct, the default access-specifier for a base class/struct is public. And when deriving a class, the default access specifier is private.

For example, program 1 fails with a compilation error and program 2 works fine.

```
// Program 1
#include <stdio.h>

class Base {
    public:
        int x;
};

class Derived : Base { }; // Is equivalent to class Derived : private Base {}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.x = 20; // Compiler error because inheritance is private
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

// Program 2
#include <stdio.h>

struct Base {
    public:
        int x;
};

struct Derived : Base { }; // Is equivalent to struct Derived : public Base {}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.x = 20; // Works fine because inheritance is public
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can a class derive from a struct, and can a struct derive from a class?

Comment: What's the reason for default access becoming private, when it's public in the parent?

Answer (score 30):

Of course. In C++, structs and classes are nearly identical (things like defaulting to public instead of private are among the small differences).

Comment: Among? Are there any others?

Comment: @AaronFranke fair enough, IIRC, there are exactly two differences, which both can be described by my response: 1. defaulting to publicly inheriting, and 2. members default to `public` visibility.

So in essence, these two are the same:

`struct T : Base { int x; };`

and

`class T : public Base { public: int x; };`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, c++ struct is very similar to c++ class, except the fact that everything is publicly inherited, ( single / multilevel / hierarchical inheritance, but not hybrid and multiple inheritance )
here is a code for demonstration

```css
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct parent
{
    int data;
    parent() : data(3){};           // default constructor
    parent(int x) : data(x){};      // parameterized constructor
};
struct child : parent
{
    int a , b;
    child(): a(1) , b(2){};             // default constructor
    child(int x, int y) : a(x) , b(y){};// parameterized constructor
    child(int x, int y,int z)           // parameterized constructor
    {
        a = x;
        b = y;
        data = z;
    }
    child(const child &C)               // copy constructor
    {
        a = C.a;
        b = C.b;
        data = C.data;
    }
};
int main()
{
   child c1 ,
         c2(10 , 20),
         c3(10 , 20, 30),
         c4(c3);

    auto print = [](const child &c) { cout<<c.a<<"\t"<<c.b<<"\t"<<c.data<<endl; };

    print(c1);
    print(c2);
    print(c3);
    print(c4);
}
OUTPUT 
1       2       3
10      20      3
10      20      30
10      20      30
```