# Struct inheritance vs class inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, memcpy

I just discovered from this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979211/struct-inheritance-in-c) that structs are inheritable in C++ but, is it a good practice, or is it preferable to use classes? In which cases is preferable and in which ones is not?

I have never needed this, but now I have a bunch of messages of different types, but same longitude. I got them in binary in a char array, and I just copy them with memcpy to the struct to fill its fields (I don't know if it is even possible to do it with std::copy).

I guess it would be great to be able to inherit every struct from a base struct with common headers, that is why I searched for this. So a second question would be: if I do this with classes, is it possible to do a memcpy (or std:copy) from a buffer to a class?

Comment: In C++ structures and classes are almost the same, the only difference being that for `struct` the default visibility is `public` while for classes it's `private`.

Comment: What do you plan to put in the base struct?

Comment: There is one more difference between `class` and `struct`, which affects inheritance specifically: The default mode of inheritance is `private` with `class`, but `public` with `struct`. So when you do `struct D : A`, this will be the same as `struct D : public A`. But that should not stop you from using inheritance with `struct` of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether you can use a bitwise copy or not has nothing to do with the `struct` or `class` tag and only depends on whether said `struct` or `class` [`is_trivially_copiable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable). Whether they are is defined in the Standard (9/6 [class]) and *it basically boils down to not having to declare any other special member methods than constructors*.

The bitwise copy is then allowed by the Standard in 3.9/2 [basic.types]

> For any object (other than a base-class subobject) of trivially copyable type `T`, whether or not the object holds a valid value of type `T`, the underlying bytes (1.7) making up the object can be copied into an array of `char` or `unsigned char`. If the content of the array of `char` or `unsigned char` is copied back into the object, the object shall subsequently hold its original value. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> #define N sizeof(T)
> char buf[N];
> T obj; // obj initialized to its original value
> std::memcpy(buf, &obj, N); // between these two calls to std::memcpy,
>                            // `obj` might be modified
> std::memcpy(&obj, buf, N); // at this point, each subobject of `obj`
>                            // of scalar type holds its original value
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

*Note: a bitwise copy of padding bytes will lead to reports in Valgrind.*

Using `std::copy` to the same effect:

```
char const* b = reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&obj);
std::copy(b, b + N, buf);
```

Comment: Ok, so it is possible to do it with classes. Are padding bytes the reason of using #pragma pack? And one more question: could you edit your answer and add the same code using std:copy? I know compiler will most likely change if back to memcpy, but I'm curious about how to call std:copy for this task

Comment: @RomanRdgz: `#pragma pack` will indeed remove padding bytes (well `pack(1)` will, `pack(2)` may not) at the cost of *correctness*. However, padding bytes are introduced to respect alignment constraints on the types, so removing them equates to violating those constraints. On x86, the code will work, but access to the mis-aligned parts will be slower (the CPU does extra work); on some architectures, a hardware exception may be raised (crashing the program). **Do not use it.**

Comment: Ok I see, so with a pointer to the class it is possible to use std::copy. Thanks

Comment: About the pack, the problem is that my buffer contains n bits representing something, the following m bits represent another thing... I need bit level when copying to the struct, so I need to pack. If I can't use (or shouldn't) that pragma, how would you suggest doing it?

Comment: @RomanRdgz: Two options. The portable and evolutive one is to create a routine that read from the `char` array and set each field of the structure appropriately (and back). This is typically called **serialization**. The optimized one, which is highly-platform dependent and require a new structure for each new version of the protocol, is to use **bit fields**.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between `struct` and `class` is the default access modifier to its members. In `struct` it's `public` and in `class` it's `private` (until stated otherwise). Besides that `struct` and `class` are identical in C++.
Sometimes structs are prefered for PDO (Plain Data Objects) over classes for readability but that's really up to a coding convention.

Comment: Is 'PDO' the same as 'POD' (Plain Old Data)?

Comment: also struct has public inheritance by default. struct B : A is equivalent with struct B : public A (where A is a struct or a class)

Comment: Sure, I already know that, but if structs are used for PDO just for convention, and using classes is as good solution as structs, then is it possible to use memcpy and std:cpy over a class just as I can do over a struct?

Comment: @xtofl yea, it's also a convention issue :)

Comment: @Roman Rdgz of course (you probably mean for instance of a class)

Comment: @icepack: POD has the advantage of being the acronym used in the C++ standard. Anyway, what you mean is clear.