# Converting a structure to a class?

Tags: c++, class, structure

Say we are making an address book by creating a class AddressBook. We put a variety of tools in the class, including the option to add a member. If we use a structure to keep track of each person's information, it would look like this:

```
class AddressBook {  
public:
    AddressBook()
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    void AddPerson();
    //More functions..

    struct Entry_Structure
    {
        char firstName[15];
        char lastName[15];
        char idNumber[15];
    };

    Entry_Structure entries[100];
    unsigned int count;
};
```

Then we could write the following for the AddPerson function:

```
void AddressBook::AddPerson()
{
    cout << "Entry number " << (count + 1) << " : " << endl;

    cout << "Enter subject's first and last name: ";
    cin >> entries[count].firstName >> entries[count].lastName;

    cout << "Please enter the subject's ID number: ";
    cin >> entries[count].idNumber;

    ++count;                                               
}
```

However, instead of using a **structure** for `Entry_Structure`, I used a **class**.

That is, `class Entry_Structure` instead of `struct Entry_Structure`.

What would I have to change in the program and the following function to make this work?

Comment: Please use std::string for names.  "Hugh Fearnley-Whittingstall" (a British celebrity chef) has a surname which is too long for your field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only practical difference between `class` and `struct` is that, by default, class members are `private`, and `struct` members are public.

So:

```
struct Entry_Structure
{
    char firstName[15];
    char lastName[15];
    char idNumber[15];
};
```

Is equivalent to:

```
class Entry_Structure
{
public:
    char firstName[15];
    char lastName[15];
    char idNumber[15];
};
```

Comment: The other difference is that inheritance is public by default for structs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025214/struct-inheritance-vs-class-inheritance-in-c

Comment: But it's a class in a class so Entry_Structure entries[100] won't work the same way.

Comment: @NaomiJacobson Why won't it work the same way?

Comment: No, an array of structures works exactly the same way as an array of classes.