# How to delegate all methods of a c++ part object to its composite object

Tags: c++

How can I delegate all methods of a part object to the composite class without using a get() method and call it on the Composition object:

Example:

```
struct Part {
  void f() {};
  int g(double &v) { v = 2; return 3; }
};

struct Composition {
  Part part;
};
```

The Composition class should be able to be used in this way:

```
Composition p;
p.f()
int a = p.g(2.0)
```

Additionally I want use boost::bind in this way:

```
boost::bind(&Composition:f, this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the inheritance property of structs.  See [Struct inheritance in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979211/struct-inheritance-in-c),

So, you could do

```
struct Part {
  void f() {};
  int g(double &v) { v = 2; return 3; }
};

struct Composition : Part{

};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want a class to have all the behavior of another partial class, consider inheritance instead of composition.

If you insist using composition, then you would have to manually write a set of delegate functions. For example:

```
struct Composition {
  Part part;
  void f() {return part.f()}
  int g(double &v) { return part.g(v); }
};
```

Off topic:
Function `Part::g` uses a *reference to double* so the line `int a = p.g(2.0)` is not going be be compiled any way.

Comment: Nor will your `void f() { return part.f() }`